# Android - Exoplayer - Progressive live streaming - Mpeg2 - Audio issue

Tags: android, ffmpeg, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Hi I have live stream URL ... When I tried to play with latest exoplayer version 2.11.4 .... Video is being played and audio is not playing ....

type of the url is decided based on

`int type = Util.inferContentType(uri);`

and it is ProgressiveMediaSource

i have no signs of audio log both

```
debugViewHelper = new DebugTextViewHelper(player, this.debugTextView);
player.addAnalyticsListener(new EventLogger(trackSelector));
```

but the url is played well in other players like VLC ...

and i have checked with ffprobe it is having both audio and video stream ...